# Push html attribute to array onClick

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I'm trying to push number attribute of the element to the array onclick with a simple function, but array contains only empty values separated with commas.
Here's html code.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" number="12" onclick="basket.push(this.number)">toBakset</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" number="15" onclick="basket.push(this.number)">toBakset</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" number="18" onclick="basket.push(this.number)">toBakset</button>
```

from the start "basket" array is empty.
Seems this question is so dumb but I can't find a solution :(

Comment: Be aware that using standard Javascript without libraries, IE8 (and 9, I think) can't access custom attributes. I use jQuery for custom attributes. This is in addition to changing the name of it to "data-numbers" and using one of the methods below to access the data. Or just `onclick="basket.push(12)"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

number isn't a valid attribute for the [button element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button). In order to retrieve it you would have to use a different function from the API

```
onclick="basket.push(this.getAttribute('number'))"
```

Better yet, store your `number` attribute inside of the `data-` markup like this:

```
<button data-number="5" ...
```

So that it conforms to standards. Then you would use

```
onclick="basket.push(this.getAttribute('data-number'))"
```

to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

it's because number isn't a standard attribute, so this.number isn't anything.  you have to do it another way, such as give an id to each button and keep an array containing which ids have which numbers

Answer (score 0):

- **button** *type="button"* ?
- *number* attribute ?

**Use `data-*` attributes!**

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oteNupi/2/edit)**

```
<button onclick="basketPush(this)" data-number="12" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">toBakset</button>
```

```
var basket = [];

function basketPush( that ){
  basket.push( that.dataset.number );
}
```

<sub>**DOCS:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#data-*</sub>